# Does okhttp 2.7.5 have proxy fall through?

Tags: okhttp

I moved from okhttp 2.7.5 to 3.10.0 and when I'm on a VPN where my proxy is not valid/accessible and the system properties `-Dhttp.proxyHost` and `-Dhttp.proxyPort` are set, the client requests fail with a connection timeout.  On 2.7.5, even with these system properties set, if I'm on a network where these values were invalid, it still worked.  My guess is that if the proxy was not accessible, the client would fall through to attempt the requests without the proxy.

Is this expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior changed in OkHttp 3.5. From the [changelog](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

> - OkHttp no longer attempts a direct connection if the system's HTTP proxy fails. This behavior was surprising because OkHttp was disregarding the user's specified configuration. If you need to customize proxy fallback behavior, implement your own java.net.ProxySelector.